# zeek command not found

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I have installed zeek, mongo, rita on my SANS SIFT vm, however I cannot get zeek to read a wireshark pcap. I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I get the following error when running the command:

```
sansforensics@siftworkstation: ~
$ zeek -r /home/sansforensics/Desktop/3hr_test.pcapng local

Command 'zeek' not found, did you mean:

  command 'peek' from deb peek (1.5.1-1)
  command 'zerk' from deb gpsd-clients (3.20-8ubuntu0.4)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Comment: How have you installed `zeek`? Where did you install it?

Comment: I installed it alongside rita. https://github.com/activecm/rita shows install.sh will install rita as well as zeek and mongo. I can get zeekctl to run and start. Zeek folder is in /opt/zeek

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us _how you installed it_. With what command? Also, please show us the output of `echo $PATH`.

Comment: $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/rekall/bin

Comment: The command I installed zeek with was: sudo install.sh

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question to add details. If you ran `install.sh`, presumably that means you downloaded something from somewhere, right? What? From where? Also. what is the output of `ls -l /opt/zeek`? Is there a `zeek` executable there?

Comment: I have already answered this. I went here github.com/activecm/rita and it gave me instructions which I'm not going to put here due to length. Telling me to "edit" me question tells me nothing. I did tell you how I installed it. Go to the rita page and that will explain better.

Comment: Telling me to visit some other page tells _me_ nothing. The point is to have all information here. If people need to go somewhere else to understand your question, they will probably move on to the next question. The easier you make it for people to answer, the better your chances of getting an answer. Your call, of course, but if you want an answer, it is a good idea to have al information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, I suspect that the `zeek` executable is in `/opt/zeek`. However, your `PATH` variable doesn't contain that directory, which is why other programs cannot find `zeek`. So you need to add that to your `PATH`. Edit the file `~/.profile` (or, if it exists, `~/.bash_profile`) and add this line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/zeek
```

Now log out and log back in again, open a new terminal and `zeek` should work as expected.

Comment: This worked, thank you

Comment: You're welcome, @9br3ak3r. If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.